# gnome files and terminal won't open from a shortcut

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal, nautilus, desktop-shortcuts

Neither gnome files or terminal will open from a shortcut from the desktop menu.

If I type either...

```
sudo nautilus
sudo gnome-terminal
```

...they open fine.

When I try from the shortcut I just see it top left of the screen with a "loading icon" before it disappears.

This is a mostly fresh install of arch.

How can I tell what is causing this please?

Edit 1:

I am running gnome and gdm.

This is the result of

```
journalctl -b

Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost gnome-terminal.desktop[5567]: ** (gnome-terminal:5567): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost dbus-daemon[576]: Activating service name='org.gnome.Terminal'
Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost org.gnome.Terminal[576]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost org.gnome.Terminal[576]: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost dbus-daemon[576]: Activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal' failed: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 10
Nov 16 23:46:50 localhost gnome-terminal.desktop[5567]: Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 10
```

Edit 2:

This is the result of

```
localectl

System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
VC Keymap: uk
X11 Layout: gb
X11 Model: pc105
X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

This is the result of

```
locale

   System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: uk
      X11 Layout: gb
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.utf8
LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.utf8
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Edit 3:

I tried creating a new user and logging in with that. It worked a treat, for a few minutes... then worked the same way as before. I recreated the user, it worked, then stopped. Does this suggest anything?

Comment: What if you run them without `sudo`?

Comment: @muru Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.terminal

Comment: @don_crissti means the `journalctl` command.

Comment: Please see edit 2

Comment: Update: It doesn't work great. It works for a couple of minutes. Then does the same thing. Created a number of users, they all do the same... work, then don't. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what logs I should check to capture application errors?

Comment: Consider commenting the ATK bridge line in `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` (suggestion comes from [Debian bug 824226](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824226 "openjdk-8-jre: ATK bridge causes segfault when loading JR")).